# Image Length and Width in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: html, image, css

I have an `img` element with the following CSS rules:

```css
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

The original image is a square (`250px` X `250px`). The problem is that when I tested it in Internet Explorer 8, the image length and width ratio were not retained. It works in other browsers and IE9. Haven't tested yet in IE6 and IE7.

How to fix it?

Comment: If I really had to worry about still developing for IE6 in this day and age, I think I would look for a long rope and the nearest bridge. :)

Comment: @MikeBrant, need solution just for IE8.

Comment: This is a known bug in IE8 but I don't know the solution.